# Python - When building a binary with cx_Freeze, where is the code saved?

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I know its somewhere in the lib folder, and not in the actual exe, but where? I expected that, since in the lib folder there are a bunch of folders for other libraries, it creates a folder for each user-created module and saves the code there. But that is not the case, and nothing i see resembles the names of my modules. What files actually change if i change my code (no new imports etc, just simple additions) between two builds of cx_freeze?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the .pyc files in build/exe.win32-3.8/lib/library.zip.